# Javascript alert function embedded within php has issue in interpreting the message on the client side

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert

I am trying to use the javascript alert function within a php code to display a message on the client side.

```
//Show concept detail
public function showConceptDetail($concept){
    $msg ="";
    switch ($concept) {
        case 'class':
            $msg = 'Hey, I am single line with spaces';
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    return "alert('".$msg."')";
}

public function showListConcept(){
    $a= '$this->showConceptDetail()';
    $list = <<<LIST
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onClick= {$this->showConceptDetail('class')} >Class </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Object </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Variable </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member function</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inheritance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Polymorphism</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overloading</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Data Abstraction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Encapsulation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Constructor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Destructor</a></li>

    </ul>
LIST;       
    echo "List of POO concepts: ".$list;
}
```

When I try to use the function showListConcepts :

```
$a = new POOConcept();
$a->showListConcept();
```

I get a strange output at each time whenever I check the source:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert('Class" −="" this="" is="" a="" programmer-defined="" data="" type,="" which="" includes="" local="" functions="" as="" well="" data.="" you="" can="" think="" of="" class="" template="" for="" making="" many="" instances="" the="" same="" kind="" (or="" class)="" object.')="">Class </a>
```

Each space within the alert function message is exchanged by =""; I can't figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied and pasted it and ran the code that you provided. There was no problem. I did notice that the here/now docs where not in quotes. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)  Other than that there seems to be no problem. There must be some other problem. What else is going on that is processing the output? Do you have the output message anywhere else in your code or comments?

Here is my full example file named index.php followed by the output in command line.

```
    <?php

class abc
{
//Show concept detail
public function showConceptDetail($concept){
    $msg ="";
    switch ($concept) {
        case 'class':
            $msg = 'Hey, I am single line with spaces';
        break;
        default:
        break;

    }
    return "alert('".$msg."')";
}

public function showListConcept(){
    $a= '$this->showConceptDetail()';
    $list = <<<LIST
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onClick= {$this->showConceptDetail('class')} >Class </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Object </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Variable </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member function</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inheritance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Polymorphism</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overloading</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Data Abstraction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Encapsulation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Constructor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Destructor</a></li>

    </ul>
LIST;
    echo "List of POO concepts: ".$list;
  }
}  


$abc = new abc();
$abc->showListConcept();

?>
```

Then using command line.

```
sandbox>php  index.php
List of POO concepts:     <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onClick= alert('Hey, I am single line with spaces') >Class </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Object </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member Variable </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Member function</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inheritance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child Class</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Polymorphism</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Overloading</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Data Abstraction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Encapsulation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Constructor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Destructor</a></li>

    </ul>
```

On second thought:
What happens if you put quotes around the alert? Html parsers automatically add ="" if there is no quotes in place.
onClick="{$this->showConceptDetail('class')}"